# Show format time 24Hours in input type time

Tags: html, input

I have the following input

```
<input ype="time" name="appt" id="input-pickuptime">
```

and i want to show time in 24-hours format is it possible?

Comment: As per [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time), the choice of 12- or 24-hour clock depends on the system locale. There is no way to override that with the native time input.

Comment: How can i change the system locale in xampp?

Comment: you have to change it in your operating systems settings. someone from germany will see it as 24 hour input and someone from america with 12 hour input. don't try to enforce something that will turn out inconvenient for users.

Comment: Yeah but i only want to see the time as 24 Hours format

Comment: again.. you have to change it in your system settings.. https://i.imgur.com/LJr0kvh.png

Answer (score -3):

Following this [info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time), You can use min/max attributes:

```
<input type="time" name="appt" id="input-pickuptime" min="00:00" max="23:59" required>
```

Comment: this will not effect the input in browsers following the spec.